# How to capture a screenshot after each step in tests with JAVA and Cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, integration-testing

What would be the best way to capture screenshots **after each step** when running integration tests?

Tests are written in Java using Selenium(3.0.1) and Cucumber(1.2.4).

Code for taking a screenshot after a test is below, but I need a screenshot after each method annotated with @Given, @When, @Then.

```
@After
public void after(Scenario scenario){
    final byte[] screenshot = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
}
```

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: What are you really using. In your test you are saying the following. Selenium Protractor, Java, Cucumber and you mention Jasmine. That means 2 types of languages (Java and JS), and 2 frameworks (Cucumber and Jasmine). If you mean CucumberJS and Protractor then please change your question and provide the versions of CucumberJS and Protractor you are using. I can then provide you with an answer.

Comment: @wswebcreation
I have updated the question. Thanks for your comment, I was confused.

Comment: I've also updated the title and tags, because it's Java I can't help you, I'm more a JS guy ;-). Good luck with it

Comment: @wswebcreation Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this using Aspects. Was pretty tricky, note the annotation:

```
@After("call(public * cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(..)) && within(cucumber.runtime.Runtime)")
```

Below is the full code, written by Viviana Cattenazzi.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.9</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.9</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.9</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
             <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.4</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>

......

         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
             <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.10</version>
             <configuration>
                 <weaveDependencies>
                     <weaveDependency>
                         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                         <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                     </weaveDependency>
                 </weaveDependencies>
                 <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
                 <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
             </configuration>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>compile</goal>
                         <goal>test-compile</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
```

.......

**StepsInterceptor.java**

```
@Aspect
 public class StepsInterceptor {


     @After("call(public * cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(..)) && within(cucumber.runtime.Runtime)")
     public void beforeRunningStep(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Exception {

         try {
             StepDefinitionMatch stepDefinitionMatch = (StepDefinitionMatch) thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
             Step step = (Step) retrievePrivateField(stepDefinitionMatch, "step");
             String stepName = step.getKeyword().trim();

             if ("Given".equals(stepName) || "When".equals(stepName)) {
                 Object theRealStepDef = extractJavaStepDefinition(stepDefinitionMatch);
                // take screen shot here
             }
         } catch (ClassCastException exc) { ....
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where are the method definitions for retrievePrivateField(..) and extractJavaStepDefinition(..) methods?

Comment: could post the extractJavastepdefinition and retrievePrivateField method codes

Comment: @tetchen9: Where should we place this code in the framework ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. Lets assume your methods are as follows:

   ```
   @Given("^Open$")
   public void Open() throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
   }

   @When("^I$")
   public void I(String uname, String pass) throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
   }

   @Then("^User$")
   public void User() throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
   }
   ```
2. You can write a library to take screenshots like:

   ```
   public static void screenshot(WebDriver driver, long ms)
   {

   try {
       TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
       File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./ScreenShots/"+ms+"Facebook.png"));
       System.out.println("ScreenShot Taken");
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
       System.out.println("Exception while taking ScreenShot "+e.getMessage());
   }


   }
   ```
3. Now you can easily call the library after every method to take the screenshot as follows:

   ```
   @Given("^Open$")
   public void Open() throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
       Utility.screenshot(driver, System.currentTimeMillis());
   }

   @When("^I$")
   public void I(String uname, String pass) throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
       Utility.screenshot(driver, System.currentTimeMillis());
   }

   @Then("^User$")
   public void User() throws Throwable 
   {
       //your code
       Utility.screenshot(driver, System.currentTimeMillis());
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have over 600 methods that need to take screenshots. Currently looking at Aspects.

Comment: @tetchen9 Great !!! IMHO, I don't see any issue to call a library in Java when I don't have an alternative. No doubt `Aspects` would be a better option but you missed out to mention your basic requirement while framing the Question. Thanks

Comment: @GaurangShah Can you consider explaining the word `duplicate` in your comment. I always believed `libraries` are written to reuse the code. Thanks

Comment: but you are suggesting to copy past `Utility.screenshot(driver, System.currentTimeMillis());` this code in all the steps already written and all the new stpes which is going to be written. which is redundant.  it should be invoked automatically. The solution is already available in merge request as suggest earlier.

Comment: @GaurangShah I think you are missing certain points: 1. I am not claiming my Answer is the best Solution. You too can offer an Answer. 2. You are always welcome to pull from github and create/build your own exe/jar/solution in order to help yourself. 3. Here OP have come up with a Question where I didn't find a stable & proven `Listener` or `Annotation` or `tag` to offer to solve OP's Question. Hence was my simple choice to offer the concept of `library`. 4. Request to you to maintain a constructive environment beneficial to the Global Community of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

At this time, OP might have figured out alternative options. However this may help others. Latest version of io.cucumber has both @BeforeStep and @AfterStep, so you can embed screenshot capturing in to @AfterStep function at only one place which solves your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135127/5885718

Answer (score 1):

Can this post help you?

[Embedding screenshots in Cucumber JVM](https://rlogiacco.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/embedding-screenshots-in-cucumber-jvm/)

Comment: This hepls, but it only takes a screenshot after a test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible until following merge request is accepted and merged. if you are really interested you can merge it locally and have your own custom Jar.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/838

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you asked but this can help others too! (I haven't used Cucumber though)

Here is my code to take a screen shot and add it to a PDF file (If you want to do something else with it that you can).

Just you have to call `screenshotPDF(webDriver, testName)` method whenever you want!

```
package com.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.AppendMode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ScreenshotPDF {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    //public static void screenshotPDF() {
    public static void screenshotPDF(WebDriver webDriver, String testName){

                {

            PDDocument doc = null;
            boolean isNewFile = false;

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
            String timeStemp = sdf.format(date);


            try {
                try {
                    doc = PDDocument.load(new File(
                            "C:/Users/Documents/sample.pdf"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
                    doc = new PDDocument();
                    PDPage p = new PDPage();
                    doc.addPage(p);
                    isNewFile = true;
                }

                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

                Integer numberP = doc.getNumberOfPages();
                PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
                PDPage page;
                if (!isNewFile) {
                    doc.addPage(blankPage);
                    page = doc.getPage(numberP);
                } else { 
                    page = doc.getPage(numberP - 1);
                }
                PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject
                        .createFromFileByContent(screenshot, doc);
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                        doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 600);
                contentStream.drawString(testName+"  "+timeStemp);
                contentStream.endText();

                float scale = 0.4f;

                Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getCapabilities();
                String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
                if (browserName.contains("explorer"))
                    scale = 0.4f;

                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 50, 210, pdImage.getWidth() * scale, pdImage.getHeight() * scale);
                contentStream.close();
                contentStream.close();
                doc.save("C:/Users/Documents/sample.pdf");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (doc != null) {
                    try {
                        doc.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no afterStep annotation in cucumber java. So you cann't do it in straight forward. You can do it in another way as mentioned in @DebanjanB answer.

But this can be achievable in cucumber-ruby with after step annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium exposed a interfaced called as WebDriverEventListener, which you can implement you own code generally this interface has methods like afterFindBy , beforeFindBy just need to implement that method to take screen shots.

After implementing this method then you need to inject this implemented class to driver object as shown below

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
    MyWebDriverListerner handler = new MyWebDriverListerner();
    eventFiringWebDriver.register(handler);
```

Now whenever driver finds the element then it will invoke that respective injected method.

Let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: OP needs to take screenshot `after each method ` not like like afterFindBy(element)  and beforeFindBy(elemnt) as the implementation of `WebDriverEventListener`. Thanks