# How to realize addition of a screenshot after each step "Then"? Java + Cucumber + testng + maven + cucumber reports

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, screenshot

How to realize addition of a screenshot after each step "Then"? Java + Cucumber + testng + maven + cucumber reports

```
@Before
public void start(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    logger.logTestEnd(String.format("Scenario '%s' start", scenario.getName()));
    ...
}

@After
public void exitScenario(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        Screenshot.saveScreenshotInReport(scenario, BrowserManager.getDriver());
        logger.info(String.format("scenario[%s] is failed", scenario.getName()));
    }
    BrowserManager.quit();
    logger.logTestEnd(String.format("Scenario '%s' end", scenario.getName()));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture a screenshot after each step in tests with JAVA and Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298345/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-after-each-step-in-tests-with-java-and-cucumber)

Comment: Using AspectJ as described in the link by @Grasshopper

Comment: If you want to try to merge the work done on this locally and use- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/838