# After Step and before Step Cucumber

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, bdd

I want to execute something before and after **each step**(not scenario). How do I do that in Cucumber ?

Like the after and before in junit.

** I am using java.

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/838 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298345/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-after-each-step-in-tests-with-java-and-cucumber

Comment: @tetchen9 i have copied your answer , but it does not work. looks like someone need to invoke beforeRunningStep . i need full example please

Comment: Cucumber-JVM has a Before and a After annotation. It is invoked before and after each scenario. This is similar to JUnits Before and After annotations that are invoked before and after each test. I am not aware of anything that is invoked before each step. Please share more information about what you want to achieve and we might be able to help you with an alternative solution.

Comment: @Thomas Sundberg am aware of everything you have said also from the links above you can see that other people tried somehow to implement that.   before we moved to Cucumber we was using another automation tool(jsystem) and it uses junit annotations . we have a block of code that is executed before and after each step/test . i guess i have to invoke these block of code now without using these annotations.

Comment: There currently is no @AfterStep in Cucumber-JVM. See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/938 (open PR with merge conflicts)

Answer (score 3):

There should be something like AfterStep (haven't found BeforeStep yet)

`AfterStep do
  #After every step
  #this is also before the next step...
end`

If you want to filter these for certain steps, do

`AfterStep('@cucumis', '@sativus') do
  # This will only run after steps within scenarios tagged
  # with @cucumis AND @sativus.
end`

Reference: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

Comment: This is not in java

Answer (score 3):

In recent version of io.cucumber, both @AfterStep and @BeforeStep hooks are available,

```
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;

public class Hooks {

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
        System.out.println("======>  This is before step  <======");
        //Do something before executing the step
    }

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep() {
        System.out.println("======>  This is after step  <======");
        //Do something after executing the step
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

BeforeStep and AfterStep hooks are available in the latest cucumber jvm api. Just update your pom with the latest version for cucumber-jvm. For more information just go through the link below :

https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting/issues/100