# How to embed a screenshot in Cucumber report for each action taken?

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber-java

I see a post was made for this here [How to capture a screenshot after each step in tests with JAVA and Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298345/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-after-each-step-in-tests-with-java-and-cucumber)

But, what I would like to do is be able to take a screenshot after every single action taken even within a single Cucumber step and embed into the Cucumber report. In other words, there are multiple actions taken in a single step to satisfy that step and I would like to embed the screenshot for all of them. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Solved it by doing scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png"); in every page object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the @BeforeStep or @AfterStep cucumber annotation in your hook class and then call you screenshot method inside it.

```
public class Hooks{
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeEachStep(){
        takeScreenshot();
    }
}
```